# $f'$ is integrable in $[0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$ in $[0,1]$ Prove that $\ |f(x)|\le\sqrt{\int_0^1|f'|^{2}dx}$

Tags: real-analysis

I've tried this using the Cauchy inequality for integrals, but I can't get the algebra right, could anyone help me solving this? Thanks

Comment: This isn't true. Let $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Then $f'$ is integrable, but $f(0)\ne0$ and $|f(x)|>\sqrt{\int_0^1|f'|^2\ \mathrm dx}$.

Comment: sorry I wrote it wrong first time

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sqrt{\int_0^11^2\ \mathrm dx}=1$. By the fundamental theorem of calculus and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality it follows that
$$|f(x)|=|f(x)-f(0)|=\left|\int_0^11\cdot f'(x)\ \mathrm dx\right|\le1\cdot\sqrt{\int_0^1|f'(x)|^2\ \mathrm dx}.$$